# Copy for Treeview Item in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, copy

How to enable copy in my `treeviewitem` so that i can copy the text in treeview selecteditem and paste it somewhere else. I can't find such property in treeview in wpf.

here is my code

```
<TreeView 
    SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Intution Studio" ItemsSource="{Binding Main}">
        <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem Command="Copy">
                    <!-- (can't enable copy option) -->
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images\copy.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
        <TreeViewItem.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <!-- ... -->
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.Resources>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I will tell you what I did in this case. My situation was a little more complex but the general idea is when you select copy to grab all the data of the current item and store somewhere and then just insert it at a desired position. The only thing you need to know then is what you are copying and where you are putting it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry WPF does not support that.

You should solve this by cloning the underlying data in your model. If you don't have MVVM or must per se clone the visual control, the only reasonable solution seems serializing it to a xaml and then reconstructing it from that.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/209597f0-0e8b-4fbb-a69d-a6479ed96187

Comment: I am using WPF not forms. I can't use it.